# SQL/Redshift: Querying user behaviour before first purchase

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following tables:

```
Table:  users
id | created_ts | username_str
---------------------------------

Table:  activity
user_id | created_ts | activity_descr_str
---------------------------------

Table:  purchase_orders
id | user_id | created_ts | price
```

users.id is the primary key to the foreign keys user_id.
I would like to know how many users have <= 3 activities before making their first purchase.  But only for newly joined users after date X (say '2016-08-01').

Many thanks.

EDIT, 2016-10-06:

this is what I've tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM (SELECT po.user_id
             FROM purchase_orders po
        LEFT JOIN activity a USING (user_id)
        JOIN users u ON u.id = po.user_id
    WHERE   DATE (po.created_ts) >= '2016-08-01'
      AND   a.created_ts < po.created_ts
      GROUP BY 1
      HAVING COUNT(a.created_ts) <= 3)
```

Comment: Your question should include code that you have tried.  This looks like a homework-type question.

Comment: yes, you're right.  I've added my code. As I suspected my code yields very different results from yours, @GordonLinoff.  I don't quite understand why, as both seem very similar.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to break the logic into parts:

- Get the first order date for each user.
- Filter out the users that are too old.
- Join in the activities, paying attention to the dates.
- Count the number of activities per user.
- Filter and count again.

So, one method is a query like this:

```
select count(*)
from (select user_id, count(a.user_id) as num_activities
      from (select po.user_id, min(created_ts) as mints
            from purchase_orders po
            group by po.user_id
            having min(created_ts) >= '2016-08-01'
           ) o left join
           activity a
           on a.user_id = o.user_id and a.created_ts < o.created_ts
      group by user_id
     ) u
where num_activities <= 3;
```